# Can't create relationship with Account and Custom object when using FF Unit Of work

Tags: relationships, insert, design-patterns

I working on a class that needs to insert several records and create relationships between them, mostly to the Account object.

I'm passing a deserialized JSON (`WrapperRestZopaProviderRequest`) to the method that needs to create and connect these objects. 
The issue is that when I try to create a relationship to all the objects to the Account the lookup field on those objects are empty.

**This is the method:**

```
private static void insertAccount(WrapperRestZopaProviderRequest wrapperToInsert) {
        Account account = getAccount(wrapperToInsert);
        uow.registerNew((SObject) account);

        Provider_Request__c providerRequest = getProviderRequest(wrapperToInsert);
        // TODO: The Account is not showing on the provider request record
        uow.registerRelationship((SObject) providerRequest, Provider_Request__c.Account__c, (SObject)account);
        uow.registerNew((SObject) providerRequest);

        Residential_Information__c residentialInfo = getResidentialInformation(wrapperToInsert);
        // TODO: The Account is not showing up on the residential information record.
        uow.registerNew((SObject) residentialInfo);

        List<Addresses__c> address = getAddresses(wrapperToInsert);
        for (Addresses__c ad : address) {
            uow.registerNew((SObject) ad, Addresses__c.Residential_Information__c, (SObject) residentialInfo);
        }

        Financing_Request__c financingRequest = getFinancingRequest(wrapperToInsert);
        uow.registerRelationship((SObject) financingRequest, Financing_Request__c.Provider_Request__c, (SObject) providerRequest);

        uow.registerNew((SObject) financingRequest);
        //uow.registerNew((SObject) financingRequest, Financing_Request__c.Account__c, account);
        //uow.registerRelationship((SObject) providerRequest, Provider_Request__c.Account__c, account);
        //uow.registerNew((SObject) residentialInfo, Residential_Information__c.Account__c, account);

        uow.commitWork();
        System.debug(account.Id);

    }
```

On the line `uow.registerRelationship((SObject) providerRequest, Provider_Request__c.Account__c, (SObject)account);` ...

I'm expecting to insert the value of the Account to the `Provider_Request__c.Account__c` field after the unit of work is done with the commit, that is not happening. Is not happening for neither of the records when I try to set a relationship to the Account.

On the other hand the here:

```
Financing_Request__c financingRequest = getFinancingRequest(wrapperToInsert);
uow.registerRelationship((SObject) financingRequest, Financing_Request__c.Provider_Request__c, (SObject) providerRequest);
uow.registerNew((SObject) financingRequest);
```

Things are working as they should.

So the problem is with the account.

[image]

I tried to isolate the code and only try with one custom record and the Account and still fails. 
If I explicit insert an Account Id then it works... so it looks like there is not id in the relationship process. I could insert the Account first and then use the id for the other records but that is going to the UOW principles ... anyone knows what could be the issue here?

Comment: Have you checked configuration of your unit of work? Order in which those SObjects are being inserted is important in these situations. Also: there's no need to cast to `SObject` in your case (or hardly ever).

Comment: Yes, it was the order of the `fflib_SObjectUnitOfWork` objects. The `Account.SObjectType` was on the last place... is working now.

Comment: My ordering of objects in `Application.UnitOfWork` has the objects at the "highest" level in the schema first (like Account) and the objects at the lowest level last (like "Task" or "ContentDocumentLink". You also have the ability when defining the uow object to specify a custom precedence sequence of objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in comments: order of objects `fflib_SObjectUnitofWork` plays a big role here. Parent object (`Account` in this case) has to occur before child (`Financing_Request__c`). That way when parent already has an Id when child is being inserted.